# Intersection of hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra, performance

A very basic question but i couldn't find another post about it:

Given $p$ non parallel hyper-plane in $\mathbb{R}^p$:

$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
c_{11} & a_{11} & .... & a_{1p} \\
... & ... & ... & .... \\
c_{p1} & a_{p1} & .... & a_{pp} \end{array} \right)$

$||a_{i.}||=1$

What is the best (from a numerical standpoint of view) 
way to get the $p$ vector of coordinates $x$ of their 
intersection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the matrix A is non-singular, the intersection of the hyperplanes is simply the the solution of the linear system of equations $Ax=b$, where

$A= \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & .... & a_{1p} \\
... & ... & .... \\
a_{p1} & .... & a_{pp} \end{array} \right)$

and

$b= -\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
c_{11} \\
... \\
c_{p1} \end{array} \right)$

The "best" way to solve this system largely depends on the matrix A itself (see [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2068/how-do-the-properties-of-a-matrix-affect-the-linear-system-solving) , [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/81/what-guidelines-should-i-follow-when-choosing-a-sparse-linear-system-solver), or [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/513/why-is-my-iterative-linear-solver-not-converging) for more information on a choice of solver).

In the case when A is singular, we cannot describe the intersection as a single point.