# Open Source Linear Algebra Library

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, matrix, c

I am making a code in C that requires the equivalent of Matlab's '\' command for a linear system of the form AX=B where A is an NxN matrix and X, B are Nx1 vectors- i.e a code that performs X=A\B that is optimized to recognize it will be receiving a symmetric positive-definite sparse matrix. I was wondering if there is any open source code in C to do this operation.

Comment: CHOLMOD from SuiteSparse (http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) will solve systems of this type, is written in C, and is open source.

Comment: Which, incidentally, is exactly what Matlab is using if `backslash` detects an spd matrix...

Comment: precisely what I was looking for! Works perfect thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CHOLMOD](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) is definitely the go-to for if you want a direct solver. It's what MATLAB and Julia use for solving A\b with a positive-definite sparse matrix, and likely many others.

However, you may not want to use a direct solver for large sparse matrices. Since direct solvers are $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$, they tend to not do very well as the problem grows in size. Instead, people use iterative methods to iterative get solutions $Ax_n \approx b$ where the solution $x_n \rightarrow x$ as the number of iterations $n \rightarrow \infty$.

For example, since your matrix is positive definite, conjugate-gradient methods are well suited for the problem. There are tons of implementations [like this one](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/cg/cg.html) if you don't want a whole library. But then there are multigrid methods and all kinds of other things. There is a [whole CSSE question devoted to picking the right method](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/81/what-guidelines-should-i-follow-when-choosing-a-sparse-linear-system-solver). If you want a library that would make it easy to  swap around to different solvers and see which one is fastest, try [PetsC](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/linearsolvertable.html) (I linked the page which shows all of the solvers). If you're going to put some time into it and performance really matters, I would definitely go with PetsC.